# Help with simple Power calculation exercise (understanding test statistics)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-power

I have the solution of the quiz below but. in that solution, I cannot understand the choice of the test statistic and would need help to understand that. 
(I do not need help with the full solution, don't need the numeric result.)

The quiz is:
"Researchers would like to conduct a study of 100 healthy adults to detect a 
4 year mean brain volume loss of  .01 mm3. Assume that the standard deviation of four year volume loss in this population is .04 mm3. 
About what would be the power of the study for a 5% one sided test versus a null hypothesis of no volume loss?"

The solution description starts like this:
P(  X¯/(σ/sqrt(n)) > 95th N quantile | μ > .01) 
Here I do not understand why it is using just X¯ instead of (X¯-.01) 
that is, I would have expected instead:
P( (X¯-.01)/(σ/sqrt(n)) > 95th N quantile| μ > .01)

Can someone explain this in a simple/clear way?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under you null hypothesis, the distribution of the test statistic $X$ is $N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$. If $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, then $\frac{X}{{\sigma}/{\sqrt{n}}}$ is equivalent to $Z$.

Your rejection region is defined $X>x$ where $P(X\le x)=0.95$; i.e. we want the 95th quantile of $X$. We can express $x$ in terms of the *standard normal quantiles*.

$$P(X\le x) = P\left(\frac{X}{{\sigma}/{\sqrt{n}}}\le \frac{x}{{\sigma}/{\sqrt{n}}}\right) = P\left(Z \le \frac{x}{{\sigma}/{\sqrt{n}}}\right)$$

$$\frac{x}{{\sigma}/{\sqrt{n}}} = \text{95th Standard Normal Quantile}$$

$$x = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\text{95th Standard Normal Quantile}\right)$$

Now we suppose that under the alternate hypothesis, the distribution of the test statistic $X^-$ is $N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$

Using the definition of power, we need

$$P(X^->x) = P\left(X^-> \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\text{95th Standard Normal Quantile}\right) \right)$$

$$ = P\left(\frac{X^-}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}> \text{95th Standard Normal Quantile} \right)$$

Comment: Ok, so the mean I was ... "missing" was actually there but not written explicitly because it's 0 under the H0.
Thanks you for your very clear and helpful answer

Comment: @user778806 You are welcome; if everything is clear you can 'accept' my answer as well.

Comment: Was not clear to me how to accept, was expecting an accept button or link.
I think I've accepted it now, if not let me know.